# springboot Logback conflicting with an implementation on the dependency I recently added to my project

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, avro

I recently added avro-tools 1.8.2 to my project POM. It has it's own implementation of slf4j loggerfactory. Cannot exclude logback as all my logging till now is based on this. What is the best options to over come this. Due to dependency conflict, I am getting below exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from jar:file:/Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/Workspaces/GitHub/central-ops/target/central-ops-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/avro-tools-1.8.2.jar!/). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:346)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:273)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:97)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:230)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:209)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.walmart.Application.main(Application.java:33)
```

This the stack trace I am getting when starting the spring boot jar with build in tomcat.

Comment: can't we exclude the slf4j dependency with  compile('avro-tools:1.8.2'){
   exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
}

Comment: It is Apache API. Can we get source and compile without it? Let me see if I am able to get the source.

Answer (score 0):

The Log4jLoggerFactory is implemented in avro-tools.jar, it is not included by define a dependency in its pom file, so you cannot exclude the implementation.

To solve the issue, you can add the logback dependency explicitly in pom file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
```